# Detecting cellular network using connman

Tags: unix, networking, dongle, lte, connman

I am using connman as my network manager. i have plugin a Airtel LTE(Huawei E-382) dongle to my system(ubuntu 12.04).It is working perfectly fine and output of ifconfig showing eth0, wlan0 and ppp0(for this dongle) as interfaces. but while listing technology using connman- 
**./connmanctl technologies**, only ethernet, bluetooth and wifi technologies is visible. i could not find **cellular** network.

my connman version is 1.15.

if any one have any idea pls share.

thanks!

Comment: This seems to be quite a mystery... I've been looking for such answers for quite long.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: Has anybody found any solution?